# When to Use the "pure" Keyword in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity

I have some confusion about when and how to use the "pure" keyword in the Solidity programming language. Therefore, I would like to clarify the usage of the "pure" keyword in Solidity. Simple examples of where it can be useful would be helpful.

What I am trying to do is understand how and when to use the "pure" keyword in the Solidity programming language. I have added it to some programs, but I haven't fully grasped what advantages it can provide. My expectation is to gain clarity regarding the usage of the "pure" keyword. In reality, the "pure" keyword needs to be explained with examples from Solidity.